# Incluir arquivos na view codeigniter

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, codeigniter

Olá, estou tetando chamar um arquivo js/css que se encontra dentro de *application/views/app.js*, porém estou tentando incluir o mesmo dentro de uma view que se contra na mesma pasta *application/views/login.php* mas um erro 403 é retornado, alguém tem alguma solução para isso?

**EDIT**

Achei uma helper que talvez ajude, ela gera uma hash chamando o arquivo mas ainda está dando erro 403

```
if (!function_exists('link_ng'))
{
    function link_ng($js = "")
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        $base_principal = $CI->config->slash_item('base_url');
        $version = hash("haval160,4" ,(date('YmdHis')));

        if ($js!='')
        {
            return "<script src='".$base_principal."app/views/{$js}?v={$version}' language='javascript' type='text/javascript'></script>";
    }
    return "";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom depois de tanto procurar em fóruns gringos achei uma solução cabível, dentro da pasta *application*, o arquivo *.htaccess* se encarrega de bloquear todas as requisições diretas aos arquivos, essa prática não é muito recomendada, sendo que uma vez utilizada de maneira errada pode deixar brechas no sistema, segue o código que deve ser substitutivo pelo conteúdo do *application/.htaccess*, caso não exista crie o arquivo:

```
# deny *everything*
<FilesMatch ".*">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# but now allow just *certain* necessary files:
<FilesMatch ".*\.(js|JS|css|CSS|jpg|JPG|gif|GIF|png|PNG)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Você pode mudar para aceitar outros arquivos, o acesso direto aos arquivos da view .php por exemplo ainda serão bloqueadas.

Answer (score 1):

Olá! Erro 403 é permissão negada. Você não pode e não é permitido acessar arquivos do diretório `/application` diretamente via um caminho na URL. Arquivos abaixo da `/application` são exclusivos para uso do framework do Codeigniter.

Para referir-se a um arquivo como um javascript, crie um diretório `/js` irmão do `/application` e monte o endereço assim, se utilizando seu helper:

```
return "<script src='".site_url('js/'.$js.'?v='.$version)."' language='javascript' type='text/javascript'></script>";
```

Senão escreva diretamente no HTML a importação do script javascript:

```
<script src="<?=site_url('js/meu_javascript_monstro.js')?>" language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```